# Sort multi-dimensional array with usort

Tags: php, usort

The following usort function does not always give the right result since it will only "push" up or down one position relative to the compared item. Thus when performing the sort multiple times the result `Yes No Yes No`can occur.

The function successfully sort field b.

How can I solve this?

array

```
[0] => array("a"=>"Yes","b"=>"apple"...);
[1] => array("a"=>"Yes","b"=>"banana"...);
[2] => array("a"=>"No","b"=>"lemon"...);
[3] => array("a"=>"No","b"=>"grape"...);
...
```

current function

```
function sortAnserDesc($x, $y){
    if ( $x['a'] == $y['a'] )
     return 0;
    else if ( $x['a'] < $y['a'] )
     return 1;
    else
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you are saying. For me, it works. What PHP version are you using? How are you calling usort function?

Comment: I wrote the array manually, you should be able to reproduce the error when sorting 6+ fields that contains yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good function on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#103722
And I think you have a general problem.

I try to display the callback function for usort here.

```
 function usortByArrayKey($key, $asc=SORT_ASC) {
    $sort_flags = array(SORT_ASC, SORT_DESC);

    if (!in_array($asc, $sort_flags))
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('sort flag only accepts SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC');

    return function(array $a, array $b) use ($key, $asc, $sort_flags) {
                if (!is_array($key)) { //just one key and sort direction
                    if (!isset($a[$key]) || !isset($b[$key])) {
                        throw new Exception('attempting to sort on non-existent keys');
                    }
                    if ($a[$key] == $b[$key])
                        return 0;
                    return ($asc == SORT_ASC xor $a[$key] < $b[$key]) ? 1 : -1;
                } else { //using multiple keys for sort and sub-sort
                    foreach ($key as $sub_key => $sub_asc) {
                        //array can come as 'sort_key'=>SORT_ASC|SORT_DESC or just 'sort_key', so need to detect which
                        if (!in_array($sub_asc, $sort_flags)) {
                            $sub_key = $sub_asc;
                            $sub_asc = $asc;
                        }
                        //just like above, except 'continue' in place of return 0
                        if (!isset($a[$sub_key]) || !isset($b[$sub_key])) {
                            throw new Exception('attempting to sort on non-existent keys');
                        }
                        if ($a[$sub_key] == $b[$sub_key])
                            continue;
                        return ($sub_asc == SORT_ASC xor $a[$sub_key] < $b[$sub_key]) ? 1 : -1;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            };
}
```

And to integrate with your code, you might have something like:

1. Sorting `a` value only by DESCENDING.

   `usort($YOUR_ARRAY, usortByArrayKey('a', SORT_DESC));`
2. Sorting `a` and `b`.

   `usort($YOUR_ARRAY, usortByArrayKey(array('a', 'b')));`
3. More on sorting `a` and `b` by DESCENDING

   `usort($YOUR_ARRAY, usortByArrayKey(array('a', 'b')), SORT_DESC);`

Hope this help!!

Comment: generates Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /file.php on line 100

Comment: I forget to say, this only works in PHP 5.3.x. or higher What is your PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly use [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function?

```
function sortAnserDesc($x, $y){
    return strcmp($x['a'],$y['a']);
}
```