# Sort array with the highest points

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How do I sort an array with the highest points?

Example:

```
$sale = array();

Array
(
   [UserA] => Array
        (
            [unsuccessful] => 0
            [Points] => 31
            [procesing] => 4
        )
   [UserB] => Array
        (
            [unsuccessful] => 4
            [Points] => 200
            [procesing] => 1
        )
   [UserC] => Array
        (
            [unsuccessful] => 3
            [Points] => 150
            [procesing] => 55
        )
)
```

Sort by points, it should be in order: UserB, UserC, UserA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['Points'] - $a['Points'];
});
```

The [`uasort()`](http://php.net/uasort) and [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) functions take a callback that should specify exactly what makes one item greater or lower than another item. If this function returns `0`, then the items are equal. If it returns a positive number, then the second item is greater than the first item. Else, the first item is greater than the second.

The difference between `uasort()` and `usort()` is that `uasort()` also keeps the keys, while `usort()` does not. Also take a look at [the comparison of array sorting functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) to find out about all the other ways you can sort arrays.

Comment: You can simplify the actual comparison using `return $a['Points'] - $b['Points']`.

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig, great idea, thanks. It's `$b - $a` though, since the results should be sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function `usort` to provide your own custom sorting logic. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1):

You may find USort helpful:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Also this other article on SO.

[Sort multi-dimensional array with usort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286337/sort-multi-dimensional-array-with-usort)